# How best to organise my Visual Studio solution for Unit Tests and Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd, asp.net-web-api

I have a fresh Visual Studio 2012 solution which consists of the following projects:

x1 Asp.Net Web API project (This holds my MVC/API controllers)

x1 Services project (based on the ASP.NET Empty Web Application template)

I've created two additional projects for the above (based on the ASP.NET Empty Web Application template) which I've labelled as my test projects.

I'm slowly getting my head around the whole TDD and DI approach to development hence my brain is a little swiss cheesed at this late hour.

I would like guidance on where I should setup DI and my unit tests.  The approach I'm taking is to put as many of my methods in to my 'services' project.  My main Web API project has a reference to my services project, so I can access all my public methods from that class library (I think that's the correct terminology).

I've now hit a brain block!  I want to unit test as much as possible all the methods I expose in my services project.  However my DI container (Castle Windsor) is only setup in my main API project, given that it has controllers etc.

So question:

1. For my services project do I just forget DI and write my unit tests direct to the concrete classes/interfaces?  The reason I ask is because the Castle Windsor examples I've seen have been around setting up a container for my controllers/MVC web application and then instantiating the container via the application startup in global.ascx.  If I should be using DI in my services project, how would I instantiate a container and where?
2. Following on from question 1, I wanted to gauge peoples opinions on where/how to structure all my unit tests.  The easiest place to stick my tests would be in my main Web API project, given that everything I'm doing is either directly coded in that project or pulled in as a reference (my services project in this case).

That said I would imagine it would be better to have tests written exclusively for my services project, of which are contained in their own project.  That way I can test my methods without the Web API project being involved at any level.  Who knows, the Web API project might get canned but the services project is recycled for a different platform (hopefully you can see where I'm going with this).

The end goal of all this is to have most of my methods held in a services project, reusable for other projects in whatever form they may come.  To have my Web API and other future MVC web applications pull functionality from my services library.  All the while I have maintainable, manageable and above all 'testable' projects.

I'm at the start of my development cycle and doing all that I can in reading articles and reaching out to those in the know to get best advise so I can create solid foundations for my project.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30281213/1837329

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions: use an IOC container like Castle Windsor where you **wire up your components**. If you don't wire up components in your services project, there's no need for an IOC container there. It IS however a good idea to apply DI in your services project.

Sidebar: I think you might be confusing DI with IOC containers: DI is just a principle that states that you don't just "new up" dependencies, but rather asks them nicely (through a constructor, setter, whatever). IOC containers are a step further and will do much of the heavy lifting once manually managing your dependencies becomes a burden. I like to handwrite my unit tests and NOT use a container like castle windsor there so I really *feel* the pain of having too many dependencies in a class and can do something about that smell instead of having the container act like a deodorant. There are some cases where I make an exception and do use an IOC container in my unit tests, for example for legacy code with huuuuuge lists of difficult dependencies.

On your unit test question: some people like to stick them in the same project. I personally like to put them in a **separate project that only contains tests** so I can't "cheat". By cheating I mean the following: one of the reasons to write unit tests is to highlight painful parts in your code (this is what's called "listening to your tests"). By putting tests in the same project as your production code you can more easily reach into the internals of your objects (through the "internal" visibility keyword, for example). That's almost always a design smell and this smell is made more clear when your tests can't access your production code through its internals and have to use the public API.

Finally: it's super awesome that you're thinking about this stuff at the start of your project. This is when it's easiest to introduce practices like unit testing because you don't have a large -untestable- legacy codebase yet. Don't give up, it's definitely worth the effort once you get the hang of it!

Answer (score 1):

You wire up your IOC container during application startup.  Generally speaking, the code that initialises the container should be the only production code that knows what container you’re using.  There can be exceptions, but they should be few and far between.  Since you’re creating a binary dependency between your MVC project and your service project, you should only have a single container, created in your MVC project.

There are two main approaches you can follow for setting up your container.  You can either setup all of your mappings/mapping rules within the MVC project, or you can split the responsibility so that your MVC project calls out to each library it depends on with the library having responsibility for the mappings within it.  Which approach is best, is going to depend on various things including the complexity of your required mappings.

As I’ve said, with either approach to registering your mappings, the majority of your code shouldn’t know about your IOC.  You should be writing your code to depend upon interfaces, which in production will be injected in by your container.  When you are writing your unit tests then you get to decide what it makes the most sense to inject.  Depending what you’re trying to test, you can then inject a real dependency or a Mocked/Stubbed dependency in order to allow you to have more control over the flow through your code under test.

I would strongly recommend not putting your tests in the same project as your production code.  Whilst it may be slightly easier to get it up and running, it comes with some downsides / risks.  Your assembly will need to add references to anything that your tests rely on (testing frameworks, mocking frameworks etc.).  The last thing I would want to do is deploy test code to a production server, at the very least it adds bulk to your binary at worst it introduces security vulnerabilities.  You also run the risk of accidently creating a dependency on one of your test classes (such as a helper method).  If you put your tests in a separate class library that depends on your production code then these dependency issues go away.

I tend to create a unit test project for each production project.  Depending on what I’m writing, I might make use of the `InternalsVisibleTo` property to allow my test project to see internal classes.  I might also create one or more integration test projects.  Having an integration test project that uses something like Selenium would allow you to validate that your MVC project actually works end to end which is an important aspect of testing to consider.  It’s very easy to get carried away with dependency injection and unit testing.  You write a whole bunch of code, paired with unit tests and then it falls over when you run it for the first time because you haven’t set your container up properly.