# How to organise a structure of n-tier app. for DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, n-tier-architecture

I am new to n-tier application and I need a little help with starting and organising a structure of such applications. I have read a few articles and blogs about the advantages of this type of design and I realised it is complex but worth learning. In the end, I am aiming to apply DI for maintainability and easier testing.

This might sound trivial but currently the first problem I found is shall I follow any conventions of a modular structure to properly delegate the logic and functionality, and then what would be conventions of naming such modules according to their purpose. I did try to start by myself but I struggle to find (1) a proper structure of an application, as well as (2) which object should fall into which module.

I thought I could start from a something relatively simple to test. The project I think of is a classic one and consists of a few tables, such as student, module, department, teacher. Possible queries:

1. Tables: Student, Module, Teacher, Department
2. Functions:

   - CRUD of all tables
   - Student:

     - list all students
     - average score
     - list students grouped by a module
     - list of students grouped by a teacher
   - Teacher:

     - list of modules taught by a teacher
     - List of average students' grouped by a teacher
     - List of average students' grouped by a teacher and a module
   - Module:

     - List of modules
     - List of average students' score grouped by a module
     - average score grouped by a module
   - Department:

     - List of departments all departments
     - List of departments grouped by a teacher
     - List of departments

I have also tried to create a basic n-tier structure including these layers: Presentation, BusinessLogic, DataAccess, and Data. I don’t know if I am doing this right. This is first time I have started anything related to n-tier applications and DI so please bear with me. Also, I will be grateful for any reviews.

The structure:

```
+ Presentation (Root Layer)
+---- HomeController
+---- DepartmentController
+-------- DisplayList
+---- StudentController
+-------- DispayList
+---- ModuleController
+-------- DisplayList

+ BusinessLogic (Middle Layer)
+---- MapObject
+-------- MapStudent2StudentVM
+-------- MapDepartment2DepartmentVM
+-------- MapModule2ModuleVM
+---- Repositories
+-------- Students
+------------ CRUD
+------------ ReturnList including grouping, filtering, ordering
+-------- Modules
+------------ CRUD
+------------ ReturnList including grouping, filtering, ordering
+-------- Departments
+------------ CRUD
+------------ ReturnList including grouping, filtering, ordering
+---- Services
+-------- Students
+------------ GetListOfStudents
+------------ CalculateAverageScore
+------------ GetTopXStudents
+-------- Modules
+------------ GetListOfModules
+------------ GetModulesPerDepartment
+------------ GetListOfStudentsPerModule
+-------- Teacher
+------------ GetListOfTeachersPerDepartment
+------------ GetListOfStudentsPerTeacher
+-------- Departments
+------------ GetListOfDepartments
+------------ GetStudentAverageScorePerDepartment
+-------- Calculations
+------------ CalculateAverage
+------------ FindMaximum

+ DataAccess (Bottom Layer)
+---- DataContext
+-------- ObjectDefinition (OnModelCreation)
+-------- Configuration
+------------ StudentEntityConfiguration
+------------ DepartmentEntityConfiguration
+------------ ModuleEntityConfiguration
+-------- Seed
+------------ LookUpsForDepartment
+------------ LookUpsForModules
+------------ LookUpsForStudents

+ Data (not in Code First)
+---- < Code First design >
```

Comment: check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30281213/1837329 if it's not enough i can post something else here

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I'll go and have a read through the post. ty.

Comment: @DavidArno I did not know it would be an issue but I have deleted the Q in Programmers. Is it why I've got -1?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I read through it. It is a good answer and partially answers mine, thanks, but I am still confused about what conventions are to name modules, in general. I came across names such as: Business Logic, Services, Infrastructure, Repository, Provider, Domain logic, presentation, including one of the comments to your answer where a person included the name "Common" but at least ti was explained. etc. I cannot find answer to this. All tutorials, books, blogs, articles somehow assume this is well known. Cheers!

Comment: Personally i do not name my modules explicitly  business, services ... for me it's less important than organizing them in a modular way and separate responsibility.  i prefer the idea of 'NameofyourSolution'.xxxxx  xxxx is everything you and your team can come up with to describe what is it doing